# What is the help() syntax for finding the documentation of a method (eg. groupby) of a python module (eg. pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

Stuff that I have tried on the Terminal and has not worked is as follows:

import pandas as pd

help(pd.groupby)

pd.groupby()??

help(groupby)

Comment: There's no pd.groupby. Perhaps you meant `help(pd.DataFrame.groupby)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
help(pd.DataFrame.groupby)
```